# Is there a way to create an attribution model by mapping labels, messenger conversations, and Facebook campaigns?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a project where we've been using Facebook campaigns to initiate conversations on Messenger. We've also been using labels to track certain events, such as when an order is placed. Specifically, the label we use for tracking order placements is 'order placed'.

I'm looking for a way to create an attribution model that allows us to map these labels to the messenger conversations initiated by our Facebook campaigns. In other words, I want to track which conversations that originated from our campaigns resulted in the 'order placed' label.

I attempted to use the Facebook Graph API to retrieve a list of Messenger conversations that were initiated by specific Facebook campaigns and filter those conversations based on a label ('order placed') to track specific events. Here's the API query I tried:

`GET /{page-id}/conversations?fields=id,labels,messages&filters={"labels":["order placed"],"tags":["campaign_id:23858891983880095"]}`

{page-id} was replaced with the appropriate Page ID.

I requested the 'id' of the conversations, their 'labels,' and the 'messages' associated with each conversation and if it's possible campaigns too.

I applied a filter to only retrieve conversations with the 'order placed' label and that were tagged with a specific campaign ID ('campaign_id:23858891983880095').

However, I encountered an issue with this query. The problem was that the 'labels' field does not exist on the UnifiedThread object in the API response. Therefore, I was unable to retrieve conversations based on their labels as I had expected.

I was expecting the API query to return a list of Messenger conversations that matched the specified criteria, allowing me to track and analyze conversations that resulted in the 'order placed' label and originated from the specified Facebook campaign.

Since the 'labels' field was not available on the UnifiedThread object, I'm seeking guidance on alternative approaches or workarounds to achieve this tracking and attribution task effectively.